# How to query the Date part only on laravel whereBetween()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Good day,

Im confuse on how can I perform a query on laravel's whereBetween function in evaluating only the Date part and disregarding the time part.

```
$startDate = '2015-04-31';
$endDate = '2015-05-01';
$totalDebit = DB::table('x_general_transactions_details')
            ->whereBetween('date_at', array($startDate,$endDate))
            ->where('account_xid',$account->xid)
            ->sum('debit');
```

the problem here is that all the transaction in '2015-05-01' is not being included because its time is not 00:00:00 that's why in order to get the transactions on '2015-05-01' i have to add one day to my `$endDate` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-04-31');
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-05-1');
$totalDebit = DB::table('x_general_transactions_details')
            ->whereBetween('date_at', array($startDate,$endDate))
            ->where('account_xid',$account->xid)
            ->sum('debit');
```

this code calculate all transactions from 2015-04-31 00:00:01 Am to 2015-05-01 00:00:01 am
if you want include all transaction on 2015-05-01 included use this code for end time

```
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2015-05-1' . '23:59:59');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user1873569.. I guess this is the easiest way to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a time to your dates, it will save you a day.

```
$startDate = '2015-04-31 00:00:00';
$endDate   = '2015-05-01 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally would just cast the database field to a date:

```
$totalDebit = DB::table('x_general_transactions_details')

        ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(date_at)'), array($startDate,$endDate))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        ->where('account_xid',$account->xid)
        ->sum('debit');
```